# How can I create a JSON payload with text containing XML in it?

Tags: json, xml, wso2, wso2-esb

I try to create an automatic `JIRA` problem reporting (in some FAULT sequences.
I make a `JSON` payload for `JIRA` APIs what works just fine for text.
I would like to however report to `JIRA` a `SOAP` request and response whereby I could investigate on the issue.

my question is how can I create a `JSON` payload with text containing `XML` in it?

I get this exception in `WSO2 ESB`

```
[2016-09-18 21:46:31,774] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.Error: Error: could not match input
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.zzScanError(JsonScanner.java:530)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.yylex(JsonScanner.java:941)
```

payload which I want to generate

```
<payloadFactory description="" media-type="json">
      <format>
                {
                "fields": {
                "project":
                {
                "key": "$1"
                },
                "summary": "$2",
                "description": "$3",
                "issuetype": { "name": "$4" } 
                                }
                }
            </format>
      <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$func:projectKey"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$func:summary"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$func:description"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$func:issueType"/>
      </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```

and I want to send some text containing XML into the parameter $func:description. When I sent only poor XML into the $func:description, the payload Factory transferred  into into JSON what is not needed in this case, the the XML is supposed to be a text - the message

```
for the completeness to get the XML message I used 

<property expression="$body" name="request"
        scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

call the end-point

```
  <property expression="$body" name="response"
    scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

and I need to know bind "request" + "response" into $func:description

Comment: Can you please add a sample payload, which do you want to create inside the ESB.

Comment: I just appended an example of the payload. thx you

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is well-formed you can simply set messageType property to application/json and do the conversion automatically. Refer [this](http://abeykoon.blogspot.com/2015/03/wso2-esb-convert-xml-to-json.html) for more details.

Or else you can use the payload Factory mediator or Enrich mediator to custom build your Json.

Comment: yes, the XML is well formatted. But the point is that I need to keep it as a text. with other words, the ESB shall see it as a text not as a XML structure

Comment: you can insert the XML inside a CDATA, this is an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

1. create the payload with the XML structure you like.
2. use JS script mediator to modify one node as CDATA.
3. change the content type.

My proxy config, please do the change you need for your requirement:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="XMLinsideJSON"
       transports="http https"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>    
        <property name="BOK" expression="//*[1]" type="OM"  scope="default"/> 
            <enrich>
                <source type="inline" clone="true">
                    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <fields xmlns="">
                                <summary xmlns=""/>
                                <project xmlns=""/>
                                <description xmlns=""/>                                                       
                                <issuetype xmlns="">
                                  <name xmlns=""/>                      
                                </issuetype>                                  
                            </fields>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>
                </source>
                <target type="envelope"/>
            </enrich>
            <script language="js">
                importPackage(Packages.org.apache.axiom.om);
                var elem= mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstElement();
                var myText = elem.getOMFactory().createOMText(elem, mc.getProperty("BOK"), OMNode.CDATA_SECTION_NODE);
                elem.addChild(myText)                    
            </script>                   
           <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>                  
            <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

My request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <payload>
         <response>
            <data>AAA</data>
         </response>
      </payload>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My response:

```
{"fields":{"summary":"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Body>\n      <payload>\n         <response>\n            <data>AAA</data>\n         </response>\n      </payload>\n   </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>","project":null,"description":null,"issuetype":{"name":null}}}
```

Comment: thnak you. I'll try it ou!

Comment: any news, can you close the question ?